# How to create a rating system for has_many - has_and_belongs_to_many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, rating-system

I have an app where:

`User has_many Openings`

`Opening belongs to User & has_and_belongs_to_many Categories`

`Category has_and_belongs_to_many Openings`

I'm trying to create a rating system where the user rates each opening per category, and am struggling to see what relations I need where. Could anyone help point me in the right direction please?

Basically I want the rating to belong to a opening_category relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using has_and_belongs_to_many association, you want the has_many through relation

Thus, you create a new model

```
class OpeningCategory
  belongs_to :opening
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Then you can use Opening has_many :categories, :through => :opening_categories, and Category has_many :openings, :through => :opening_categories.

Your rating can be done with the OpeningCategory, whether that is an average rating column, or a separate Rating model which :belongs_to :opening_categories.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes a lot more sense. I guess I would be able to tie this into the user model then also?

Comment: Cool. How then do I call each rating? I.e. @opening.categories.each do |category| then category.rating?

Comment: And also, submit a rating / create form fields for the opening_category rating? Also I believe the OpeningCategory should have_one :rating as each should only have one (5-star based) rating

Comment: @opening.opening_categories.each do |oc| oc.rating end

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do the form fields to update the rating model. I'm trying to loop through the opening_categories per opening, and allow editing the opening_categories.rating fields - so you would see the category title and the star rating fields underneath

Comment: With editing nested attributes, you need to do some extra stuff. Try using fields_for as explained in: http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Yeh I'm having some strange problem, maybe I'm missing something. I've added the loop to this gist https://gist.github.com/3389799